# Prove $f(x)=x^2$ is integrable over $[a, b]$ for any $a$ and $b$

Tags: integration, limits, proof-explanation

I need to prove that $f(x)=x^2$ is integrable over $[a, b]$ for any $a$ and $b$ and find $\int_{a}^{b}x^2 dx$.

I want to show this by finding some partition such that their under- and over-estimates $l_1,l_2,l_3...\in L$ and $m_1,m_2,m_3...\in M$ have a common limit and that this limit is then the integral.

Here's my work so far:

Partitioning $[a,b]$ into $n$ equal parts we obtain $l_n=(\frac{b-a}{n}\times a^2)+(\frac{b-a}{n}\times (a+(\frac{b-a}{n})^2)+(\frac{b-a}{n}\times (a+(\frac{2(b-a)}{n})^2)+...+(\frac{b-a}{n}\times (a+(\frac{(n-1)(b-a)}{n})^2)$

I'm struggling simplifying this. My textbook suggests using the formula for sum of squares and then I should be getting $l_n=(b-a)(\frac{a^2}{n}+\frac{n-1}{n}ab+\frac{(n-1)(2n-1)}{6n^2}(b-a)^2)$. Taking the limit as $n\to\infty$, I should then get $\frac{1}{3}(b^3-a^3)$.

I know that I will have to do a similar process with the over-estimates $m_n$ as well. I just need help simplifying the initial expression.

Comment: To be integrable, the result must be true for any partition, no?

Comment: I dont know the background from where you are trying to prove it but it can be proved for any continuous $f$. It is enough to show that for any partition $\mathfrak Z$ a refinement $\mathfrak Z'$ makes that $U(\mathfrak Z,f)\ge U(\mathfrak Z',f)$ and $L(\mathfrak Z,f)\le L(\mathfrak Z',f)$, and that $\lim_{\Delta(\mathfrak Z)\to 0} U(\mathfrak Z,f)-L(\mathfrak Z,f)=0$, where $U$ and $L$ are the upper and lower Darboux sums respectively and $\Delta(\mathfrak Z)$ is the mesh of the partition $\mathfrak Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$l_n = \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(a + k \frac{b-a}{n}\right)^2 = \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left[ a^2 + \frac{2ak(b-a)}{n} + \left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)^2 k^2 \right] = \frac{b-a}{n} \left[na^2 +\frac{2a(b-a)}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{2} (n-1) n + \left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)^2 \cdot \frac{1}{6} (n-1) n (2n-1)\right]$$
$$= (b-a) a^2 + \frac{a(b-a)^2(n-1)}{n} + \frac{1}{6}(b-a)^3 \frac{(n-1)(2n-1)}{n^2}$$
$$\to (b-a)a^2 + a(b-a)^2 + \frac{1}{3}(b-a)^3 = \frac{1}{3} \left(b^3-a^3\right) \text{ as } n \to \infty$$

where we've used $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k = \frac{1}{2} (n-1) n$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k^2 = \frac{1}{6} (n-1) n (2n-1)$

Similarly
$$m_n = \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(a + k \frac{b-a}{n}\right)^2 = \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left[ a^2 + \frac{2ak(b-a)}{n} + \left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)^2 k^2 \right]$$
$$=\frac{b-a}{n} \left[na^2 +\frac{2a(b-a)}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{2} n(n+1) + \left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)^2 \cdot \frac{1}{6}  n (n+1) (2n+1)\right]$$
$$=(b-a)a^2 + \frac{a(b-a)^2(n+1)}{n} + \frac{1}{6}(b-a)^3 \frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{n^2}$$
$$\to (b-a)a^2 + a(b-a)^2+\frac{1}{3}(b-a)^3 = \frac{1}{3} \left(b^3-a^3\right) \text{ as } n \to \infty$$

since $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k = \frac{1}{2} n(n+1)$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 = \frac{1}{6} n(n+1)(2n+1)$

So $$\lim_{n \to \infty} l_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} m_n = \frac{1}{3} \left(b^3-a^3\right)$$ as expected.

Comment: This implicitly assumes that $b > a \geq 0$. The situation is bit complicated if this condition is not fulfilled.

Comment: It suffices to show for this case - if they're both negative, then we can argue by symmetry since $x^2$ is even. If they're of opposite sign, we split the integral up into two - for $[a, 0]$ and $[0, b]$ and apply the previous argument to make sense of the integral in the region $x \leq 0$. (In fact alternatively, we note that $l_n$ and $m_n$ 'swap' when integrating in $x \leq 0$)